# Rails - rabl and gon gem return collection of joined tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

This is my first time using the rabl and gon gem.  I'm simply attempting to output the results of a query using rabl. Unfortunately, I'm not getting the proper objects back.

My controller:

```
@test = Category.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN incomes ON incomes.category_id = categories.id AND incomes.dept_id = 86').group_by { |category| category.cat_ds }
```

My rabl template:

```
collection @test
attributes :cat_code, :cat_ds
```

The result I hope to get:

```
{
    "REVENUE": [
        {
            "cat_code": 10001,
            "cat_ds": "REVENUE",
            "id": 1,
            "incomes": [
                {
                    "category_id": "1.0",
                    "chart_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2013-01-15T16:43:52Z",
                    "dept_id": 4,
                    "feb": "11.0",
                    "id": 1,
                    "jan": "12.12",
                    "note": "Testing",
                    "updated_at": "2013-01-15T16:43:52Z",
                    "year_id": 1,
                    "total_cost": 23
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "EXPENSE": [
        {
            "cat_code": 10002,
            "cat_ds": "EXPENSE",
            "id": 2,
            "incomes": [
                {
                    "category_id": "2.0",
                    "chart_id": 2,
                    "created_at": "2013-01-15T16:43:52Z",
                    "dept_id": 86,
                    "feb": "45.0",
                    "id": 3,
                    "jan": "60.0",
                    "note": "Two",
                    "updated_at": "2013-01-15T16:43:52Z",
                    "year_id": 1,
                    "total_cost": 105
                },
                {
                    "category_id": "2.0",
                    "chart_id": 2,
                    "created_at": "2013-01-15T16:43:52Z",
                    "dept_id": 86,
                    "feb": "45.55",
                    "id": 5,
                    "jan": "3454.0",
                    "note": "One",
                    "updated_at": "2013-01-15T16:43:52Z",
                    "year_id": 1,
                    "total_cost": 3499
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've removed most of the results above.

The results I'm getting:

```
{

        "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": [
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            },
            {
                "[#<Category id: 1, cat_code: 10001, cat_ds: \"INPATIENT REVENUE\">]": {}
            }
        ]
    }
```

So for every group like Revenue and Expense its returning one record, the same record.  Why would it simply not parse the instance variable I gave it.  What else is it doing to the data before presenting it.

Also worth to note, if i skip the rabl template and use the variable from gon, it displays perfectly.  So it must be something to do with my rabl template?

**Edit**
I want to see if the below worked, but I get the following error:
`Cannot find rabl template 'income/index' within registered ([]) view paths!`

```
def index
    @test_obj = Category.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN incomes ON incomes.category_id = categories.id AND incomes.dept_id = 86').group_by { |category| category.cat_ds }
    @test = Rabl::Renderer.json(@test_obj, 'income/index')
    gon.rabl "app/views/incomes/index.rabl", as: "test"        
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your controller. Rabl is used to render, so if you want to use it to pass to gon I think you have to render it manually since you will render HTML for the request.

```
@test_obj = Category.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN incomes ON incomes.category_id = categories.id AND incomes.dept_id = 86').group_by { |category| category.cat_ds }

@test = Rabl::Renderer.json(@test_obj, 'test/show')
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that helps. Another question though, I get the following error: `Cannot find rabl template 'income/index' within registered ([]) view paths!` Any ideas? I've updated my question.